# Styling where intext styling already exists (How to over ride)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a website built on a CMS. The custom pages generate html with styling added to the elements, rather than on a style sheet.

I need to remove the background-color property on the span elements that are under any div of class .page_text, or change it to none.

Apologies for ugly block of html:

```
<div class="page_text">
  <h2 dir="ltr" style="line-height: 1.15; margin-top: 10pt; margin-bottom: 2pt;">
     <span style="font-weight: normal;">
       <p dir="ltr" style="line-height: 1.15; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt; display: inline !important;">
     <span style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Arial; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">If you’d like to contribute to Trashswag you can submit “reports” in several ways.</span></p></span><br></h2>
```

I need to remove the background-color property. Using Chromes inspect element feature, a selector along the lines of

`.page_text h2 span {background-color: none;}` should work. It does not.

Can anyone point out how to select all spans that are within .page_text ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your attempt.

As @Tigran Petrossian mentioned, you need to use `!important` due to the inline styles. However, you also need to use `transparent` instead of `none` (which is an invalid value for `background-color`).

This will work:

```css
.page_text h2 span {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

(You could instead use `background: none !important`, which works due to implicitly setting `background-color` to its initial value of `transparent`. [More info.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background))

Answer (score 2):

Inline styles always have [a higher specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity), so you'll have to use `!important`.

`.page_text h2 span {background-color: none !important;}`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer Tigran. I added two lines to the bottom of my stylesheet and it does not seem to be helping. The page in question is here, if you have a sec I'd be really grateful if you could tell me how to get the background off the text: http://tinyurl.com/kdc599k